# Codeigniter Application and moodle to integrate

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I have one moodle application and one CodeIgnitor application at front end . The moodle db is exporting daily in CI DB Tables.
Now my client needs to integrate or merge these two system to eliminate the cron job for all data exporting importing.
Now the required job is to create this CodeIgnitor application into moodle as a plugin.

I am stuck in this one how to start or please suggest any good idea to merge these two apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the existing Web Services Functions Moodle provide, as a data provider to your CodeIgniter application. Or if the currently existing functions don't satisfy your requirements you should create a local plugin in Moodle.
Local plugins are the general form of the plugin in Moodle. They don't have a restriction on how to use them, so you can create your plugin using CodeIgnitor or any other framework. And still have access to Moodle core API and you can extend web services also.
What I love about Local Plugins is how you can use anything from Moodle in your custom application without breaking Moodle. Unlike if you are trying to put your app in the root directory and trying to use Moodle Core.